# Rename PDF file using its metadata

Tags: windows, pdf, rename, metadata

When I download a paper from Google Scholar it has a nonsense filename. Is there any way to automatically rename filename of a PDF file to its title? I would like do this using context menu in Windows Explorer.

I know Mendeley has a similar capability to bulk rename PDF files, but it's not easy to rename a single file without importing it to Mendeley.

I found also found http://www.a-pdf.com/. Unfortunately it can not fetch file metadata using internet. Commonly PDF citation info is not available in metadata of PDF file.

I see this question too [Using PDF MetaData to rename PDFs in MAC OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/523140/using-pdf-metadata-to-rename-pdfs-in-mac-os-x). But it's all about Mac.

Comment: Do you want to rename based on existing PDF metadata, or first "fetch file metadata using internet"?

Comment: @Karan I want fetch the correct value, its source is not important. Generally such data is not available in file so Internet is needed.

Comment: So since the metadata doesn't already exist in the file, it should be fetched based on the paper's title? Also, which online database/source should be used for this?