# How to automate downloading several PDFs from a given webpage?

Tags: browser, automation, macros

I am trying to download PDFs from [this link](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511486876). On clicking **Read PDF**, it opens a new window with PDF in it. On clicking the download button, it opens a dialog box and asks the user to specify the location to save the file.

After opening The webpage of the concerned e-book, I want to automate the following steps:

1. **Read PDF** is clicked. The window is opened in new window.
2. *Download icon* is clicked. Dialog box appears and asks to specify the file name and the location.
3. The default name provided is kind of gibberish. So, the meaningful name like **Frontmatter**, **Contents** etc. is paseted there which is mentioned ahead of the download link and has been copied previously.

I want to automate above steps for a lot of ebooks. Had the links been in *non-javascript form*, it would have been easy to download using some kind of download manager.

*(PS : The given webpage may not have all the **Read PDF** links activated but they are all active behind the proxy at my location.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following JavaScript for you:

```
var ar = $('a.pdf-icon').each(function (a) 
{
  var ar = $(this).attr('onclick').split("'"); 
  var url = "http://ebooks.cambridge.org/open_pdf/" 
           + ar[3] 
           + "?pubCode=CUP&urlPrefix=cambridge&productCode=cbo";   
  alert("Press OK for next download");
  window.open(url);
});
```

To execute it, open the page you linked in your question, open JavaScript console (CTRL+SHIFT+I), and paste the above code into the console and press return. It will download all linked PDFs then.

Please note:

- I tried this with Chrome and Firefox, both worked.
- You might need to disable the popup blocker feature, otherwise it won't work
- You might need to disable any PDF plugins you have in your browser, otherwise the PDFs might be displayed in the plugin instead of being downloaded
- The script might need to be modified if the source code of the page is different when viewed through your proxy.

Comment: It is working fine. Could you please tell a way to add some delay between two consequent downloads? They all start downloading simultaneously and the browser gets overwhelmed. Also, is there a way by which add *sensible* names to the files, as mentioned in point **3**. Sorry, I know very less of javascript so I have to ask such small questions. If not exact answer, any external link/tutorial will help too.

Comment: I added a line to the code which asks the user to press OK to proceed to the next download. I'm not aware of any ways to change the file names, I think it's only possible on the server side (so Cambridge would have to do this).

Comment: I appreciate your help, though I was looking for some kind of VB script automation to change the name of files.

Comment: Well changing the names using VB is easy, but you would have to provide a list of the file names from somewhere...

Comment: Each **Read PDF** is written is after the desired filename, like Frontmatter, Contents, etc. Is it possible to extract these filenames from source code or something and then proceed with file renaming?

Comment: As I said that's probably not so easy using JavaScript. But you might just use another software for that, see for example here: http://superuser.com/questions/523140/using-pdf-metadata-to-rename-pdfs-in-mac-os-x or http://superuser.com/questions/269058/automatic-pdf-renaming-based-on-title Some of the software in the answers is also available on other systems than Mac OS, like for example JabRef.